# Goal seek macro, changing cell reference not a hard value

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to make a goal seek macro for my excel model. Is it possible to create a macro that the `ChangingCell` is not a hard value but an equal formula that refers to a hard value.

```
Range("D1").GoalSeek Goal:=0.17, ChangingCell:=Range("D424")
```

So in this case cell D424 would be = to another cell that has a hard value in it. The reason why I can set the `ChangingCell` directly to D424 is that the goal seek reference for the changing cell changes based on various selections on the file.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a range object for the cell that will be changing by using the DirectPrecedents method on cell D424.  This is assuming D424 refers only to one cell.

```
Sub MyGoalSeek()

Dim precedentRange As Range

Set precedentRange = Range("D424").DirectPrecedents

Range("D1").GoalSeek Goal:=0.17, ChangingCell:=precedentRange

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Function GoalSeek(Goal As Double, ChangingCell As Range) As Double
   Dim changingCellVal As Double

   'Ensure the user only passes in a single cell, not a range of cells
   if(ChangingCell.Rows.Count = 1 And ChangingCell.Columns.Count = 1) Then
       changingCellVal = ChangingCell.Value
   end if

   'Calculate GoalSeek
   GoalSeek = 0
End Function
```